# BeanInfo in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javabeans

is there any way to edit bean's properties using some graphical interface and BeanInfo class implementation (like it's in NetBeans: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/beaninfo.html) using IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Does the bean have setters? Make a breakpoint and use the setter, via an expression evaluation? Sorry, not aware of any equivalent GUI...

Comment: @vikingsteve A [`BeanInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) is an alternative to creating getter/setter methods for defining the properties on the bean. See the [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

Answer (score 1):

No there is not anything similar to that. Even I am facing the same issue and did not find anything that works like that in IntelliJ. Its only available in Netbeans Oracle IDE for Java.

Something closer to that is [JFormDesigner](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/274) plugin for IntelliJ